# C++ Pointer to Dynamic Array of functions?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've created an array of pointer to functions, I want to know Is it possible to create array of pointer dynamically, as you see in below I want to change array length dynamically which currently is 2.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void func1(int);
void func2(int);

int main()
{
    void (*func[2])(int) = { &func1, &func2 };

    func[0](10);
    func[1](20);

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}

void func1(int n)
{
    cout << "In func1()\n\tThe value is: " << n << endl;
}

void func2(int n)
{
    cout << "In func2()\n\tThe value is: " << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: you might want to use a `std::vector`

Comment: @tobi303 actually I want use pointer, like when we create dynamic array with pointers, and don't think it be possible with vectors.

Comment: You might also want to learn about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: And whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should always be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes may be I don't know about those concepts, Is it do what I want?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Most of the time I use pointers for dynamic arrays but about this one it doesn't work actually, and I am not sure that vector works for this kind of array!?

Comment: I dont understand your comment about pointers, you can have a vector of pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a typedef for the function type:

```
typedef void (*FunctionType)(int);
```

Then make a normal dynamic array:

```
FunctionType* func = new FunctionType[2];
```

Then you can assign:

```
func[0] = &func1;
```

And call:

```
func[0](1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot these was really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the array size dynamically is to delete the pointer, and recreate it with the appropriate size.

```
//Placeholder
using Function = void(*)(int);

//We have 2 functions
Function* func = new Function[2];

//Assigning...
func[0] = &func1;
func[1] = &func2;

//Doing stuff...

//Oh no! We need a third function!
Function* newfunc = new Function[3]; //Create new array
newfunc[0] = func[0];
newfunc[1] = func[1]; //Better use a loop
newfunc[2] = &func3;

//Delete old array
delete func;

//Reassign to new array
func = newfunc;

//Now 'func' changed size :)
```

---

You would avoid all that pointer stuff using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
//Placeholder
using Function = void(*)(int);

//Create std::vector
std::vector<Function> func{ &func1, &func2 }; //Default initialize with 'func1' and 'func2'

//Do stuff....

//Oh no! We need a third function
func.emplace_back(&func3);

//Now 'func' has 3 functions
```

Comment: The problem wasn't about Dynamic array I know it, My problem was about how to create a pointer to dynamic array of functions, because in pointing function it is not possible to create like this void *(*funcs)(int) = new type[2] { &func1, &func2 };

Comment: @Bahman I understood your question as wanting to change the array dynamically, but never mind :) Hope it helps even though I understood it wrong ;D

Comment: Excuse me my friend I just read first paragraph of your answer and didn't look even in code thanks my friend, This the another solution to my problem too, I apologize again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void func1(int);
void func2(int);

int main()
{

    std::vector<void(*)(int)> funcPointers;
    funcPointers.push_back(&func1);
    funcPointers.push_back(&func2);
    funcPointers[0](10);
    funcPointers[1](20);

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```